# How to del the last part of a String in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

First of all here is my body (imagine it's only one block)

```
<resourceDescriptor name="report_mongodb_new_basic" wsType="reportUnit"  uriString="/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic" isNew="false">
<label><![CDATA[report mongodb new basic]]></label>
<description><![CDATA[test 3]]></description>
<creationDate>1330693884348</creationDate>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
    <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports.domain.ReportUnit]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
    <value><![CDATA[/reports/samples]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
    <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_ALWAYS_PROPMT_CONTROLS">
    <value><![CDATA[false]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_CONTROLS_LAYOUT">
    <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_REPORT_RENDERING_VIEW">
    <value><![CDATA[]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceDescriptor wsType="datasource" isNew="false">
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_REFERENCE_URI">
        <value><![CDATA[/datasources/MongoDB]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_IS_REFERENCE">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
```

```
<resourceDescriptor name="report_mongodb_new_basic_" wsType="jrxml" uriString="/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic_files/report_mongodb_new_basic_" isNew="false">
    <label><![CDATA[report mongodb new basic]]></label>
    <creationDate>1330693884348</creationDate>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
        <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.FileResource]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
        <value><![CDATA[/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic_files]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
        <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_IS_REFERENCE">
        <value><![CDATA[false]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_HAS_DATA">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_ATTACHMENT_ID">
        <value><![CDATA[attachment]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_IS_MAIN_REPORT">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
</resourceDescriptor>
```

I want only the first block 
( `From : <resourceDescriptor to </resourceDescriptor>` ) How can i do that in javaScript ?
**Important thing : It's not a String it's a body from an http call so I dont know what it is but not a string how to convert it to a String ?**

Thanks

Comment: You trying to parse XML or is something else going on here?  Why not describe your problem and let someone else suggest the right strategy? It's likely that the approach you've pre-selected may not be appropriate.

Comment: Why -1 ? ^^ Basically I am doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585645/http-status-code-400) But imagine before the request.put, there is a request.get which return the body which contain the xml I just write.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use the `document.getElementsByTagName()` method?

In that case just do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('resourceDescriptor')[0];
```

And you have the first of the blocks!

Comment: Thanks but It say: has no method 'getElementsByTagName', I guess I need to know what type is body first

Comment: It's an instance of httprequest http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_event_request and I can convert to a string thanks to that http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are bringing back that text as a client-side XML document. This may help with traversing and manipulating elements from the document: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_examples.asp

Comment: Actually I don't think that the var 'body' as you can see [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585645/http-status-code-400) is an xml document